# Jquery random position to multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, position, each

that is my code http://jsfiddle.net/BREvn/2/ **(it works)** but i want everyone div to be with *unique* position coordinates. Now script get the first and others move to him place. How can be possible to fix this problem? I tryed a .each function but there wasn't any results. I think this will be easy but i'm to too good in jquery/javascript.

```
$('#latestblock').animate({
  top: newY,
  left: newX
}, 500, function() { });
```

I think here must be in loop but dont know how to do it.

Comment: IDs must be unique on each document, use class instead!

Comment: you could keep the position of each div in an array, then check if the new random position overlays an existing div, if not position the div, else rerun randomizing code.

Comment: Do you want the three div's to move simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/BREvn/5/

I renamed the id to a class and created an infinite loop.
Also send the object into the moveRandom function 'moveRandom(obj)' and after de animation finishes, recall the moveRandom function with itself.

```
$('.latestblock').each(function() {
    moveRandom($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't give the same id to more than one element.

You could use a class

```
<div id='container'>
  <div class='latestblock'></div>
  <div class='latestblock'></div>
  <div class='latestblock'></div>
</div>
```

and then use `each` to animate all elements :

```
$('.latestblock').each(function(){ // <= iterates on all blocks
   moveRandom($(this)); // <= pass the block to the moveRandom function
});
```

[Complete demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f4p6b/1/)

Comment: I believe the OP wants the divs to not overlay one another

Comment: @AnPel After having see OP's fiddle, I think his goal was simpler than that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated and working version: http://jsfiddle.net/BREvn/4/

An ID must be unique, you cannot have 3 elements with the same id='latestblock'

I also called the function three times and made sure the function was using that parameter passed in.

```
moveRandom('#latestblock1');
moveRandom('#latestblock2');
moveRandom('#latestblock3');
```